# Testing react-bootstrap with mocha and ES6/babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, babeljs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to write a unit test of React and React-bootstrap components using Mocha.

All of my javascript is written in ES6, and I am using babel to transpile to ES5.

The files I am using are below.

After running `npm install`, I run `npm test`.  This fails with the following output:

```
$ npm test

> @ test /Users/tda0106/test/npm
> mocha --compilers jsx:babel-register simple-test.jsx



  A simple test
    1) "before all" hook: render and locate element


  0 passing (34ms)
  1 failing

  1) A simple test "before all" hook: render and locate element:
     AssertionError: expected null to exist
      at Context.<anonymous> (simple-test.jsx:21:9)



npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

TestUtils.renderIntoDocument is returning null for no reason that I can see.  The [TestUtil docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html#renderintodocument) indicate that `window` and `document` must be defined before importing `React`, which is the point of `test-dom.jsx`.

I am certain that `test-dom.jsx` is loaded before React, because before I added the line setting `global.navigator`,  React was throwing an error deep in its code trying to access that variable.

Any idea what I need to do to make this work?

*package.json*

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.28.5",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
      "test": "mocha --compilers jsx:babel-register simple-test.jsx"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "jsdom": "^8.4.0",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.0.1"
  }
}
```

*test-dom.jsx*

```
// React needs the basic dom objects defined before it is imported.  
// And babel moves the imports before the rest of the code. 
// So the dom setup needs to be in its own file and imported.

import jsdom from 'jsdom';


const document = jsdom.jsdom("hello world");
const window = document.defaultView;

// A super simple DOM ready for React to render into
// Store this DOM and the window in global scope ready for React to access
global.document = document;

global.window = window;

global.navigator = {userAgent: 'None'};

export default { document: document, window: window };
```

*simple-test.jsx*

```
import TestDom from './test-dom.jsx';

import { expect } from 'chai';

import React from 'react';
import { Panel } from 'react-bootstrap';

import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';


const Map = () => (
    <Panel>A map </Panel>
);

describe('A simple test', () => {
     before('render and locate element', () => {
       const renderedComponent = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
            <Map />
        );

        expect(renderedComponent).to.exist; // This fails
    });



    it('test something', () => {
        expect(1+1).is('true');
    });
});
```

*.babelrc*

```
{
    "presets": [
        "es2015",
        "react"
    ]
}
```